# ues typescript in vue3 template , compile fail

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-cli

I got a Vue3 project and i use some ts in template like:

```
<com @change="(value: string) => fn(value)"></com>
```

but the same code, when run this in my computer, its ok; in my colleague computer, fails compile. the error like:

[image]

and the project base on vue-cli.

so is there any setting allow using tupescript in vue template? and what could be the cause?

maybe shouldn't use arrow function in template, but sometimes we have to do this，for example：

```
<template>
 <!-- my-com is a component have a callback funtion [change], when my-com inner value change, it will emit the value to outer, and i would get the value and the index to do next action -->
 <my-com v-for="(item, index) in list" @change="(value) => myFunction(value, index)"></my-com>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const myFunction = (value: string, index: number) => {
// this function need my-com inner changing value and the item index to do next action 
}
</script>
```

and it cause the ts error like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call functions inside the template, even more so if typescript it's involved.
Instead, just create a function in the `script` tag where typescript is linted and active, and just call it in the template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <com @change="myFunction($event, someValue)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  const myFunction = (e: Event, val: string) => {
    // do something
  }
</script>
```

Comment: sometimes we have to call function in template, like the new description i added

Comment: If you need the event you can just `@click="myFunction($event, index)"`, I updated my answer as well

Comment: yes , i am doing like that, but vscode ts show error like I updated image